# compare first or third position

Tags: grep

The mysql general log file looks like this...

```
110822 14:41:14 103700 Query    SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `engine` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
                103700 Query    SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `engine` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
110822 15:01:14 103701 Query    SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `dbname` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
```

The thread ID 103701 can be found at the beginning or at number 3 position (after date-time)
I am using the following command to find all the queries executed in a particular thread.

> grep -w '103701' /var/log/mysql/general.log | cut -c 1-1000 | tail -10

This shows a lot of lines where 103701 number is mentioned. I am looking for this number only at first or third position.
What should the correct grep statement for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` to do this:

```
$ awk '$1 == "103701" || $3 == "103701" { print $0 }' mysql-general.log
```

Comment: When I use it shell script, something like ... # awk '$1 == "$thread_id" The variable name does not get replaced.

Comment: Wrap it with a single quote: `$1 == "'$thread_id'"`.

Comment: extraordinary answer!